# TypeError: endswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bool

Tags: python, python-3.x, count, boolean, ends-with

I was trying to count the occurrences of words which end with several suffixes. I thought that `endswith` would accept an iterable; unfortunately, it did not. Below is the code snippet:

```
s = 'like go goes likes liked liked liking likes like'
lst = s.split()
suffixes = ['s', 'es', 'ies', 'ed', 'ing']

counter = 0
prompt = 'like'
for x in lst:
    if x.startswith(prompt) and x.endswith(any(suffix for suffix in suffixes)):
         counter += 1
```

The value of `counter` should be `4` at the end of the execution. This is the error message which is displayed:

```
TypeError: endswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bool
```

How can I get the above code to work?

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly what the problem is. *" I thought that endswith would accept an iterable"* - even if it did, that's **not what you're passing it**. Try `x.endswith(tuple(suffixes))`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When passing the suffixes as an argument, it takes the first two elements and leaves the remaining ones. I have tried that already.

Comment: `[x for x in 'like go goes likes liked liked liking likes like'.split() if x.startswith('like') and x.endswith(('s', 'es', 'ies', 'ed', 'ing'))]` gives me `['likes', 'liked', 'liked', 'likes']`, which is exactly what I'd expect.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Now it is working. The first answer you suggested was passing the suffixes as an argument. Thanks for your interest and help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `any` function returns a bool value, but `str.startswith` requires a string or a tuple of strings.

You can just convert your list to a tuple and pass it to `startswith`:

```
x.endswith(tuple(suffixes))
```

Comment: I have tried your reply. `counter` evaluated to `4` only. I think it should evaluate to `5`

Comment: @Mohammed why? `'liking'` doesn't start with `'like'`.

Comment: @Kasramvd, Oh, yes. You are right. Your answer is correct. Thanks for your kind help.